# Работа с числом в памяти компьютера

Tags: c

Есть программа, которая выводит вещественное число в представлении памяти компьютера,его характеристику и мантиссу и затем обратно переводит в вещественное число для определения погрешности.
Вопрос: как можно сделать обратный перевод числа через массив с побитовым умножением на десять в двоичной системе счисления?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char charactir[8];
char mant[24];

int perevod_mant(unsigned x)
{
    for (int i = 23; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        mant[i] = x % 2 + '0';
        x /= 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
int perevod_charact(unsigned x)
{
    x += 127;
    int i;
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        charactir[i] = x % 2 + '0';
        x /= 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

int lessone(float x)
{
    int mantissa;
    while (x < 1.0)
    {
        x *= 2;
    }
    mantissa = ceilf(x * 8388608);
    mantissa = perevod_mant(mantissa);
    return 0;
}

int charact(float x)
{
    int characteristic = 0;
    if (x < 1.0)
    {
        while (x < 1.0)
        {
            characteristic--;
            x *= 2.0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (x > 1.0)
        {
            characteristic++;
            x /= 2.0;
        }
        characteristic--;
    }
    return (characteristic);
}

int morethanone(float x)
{
    unsigned mantissa;
    while (x > 1.0)
    {
        x /= 2.0;
    }
    x *= 2.0;
    mantissa = ceilf(x * 8388608);
    mantissa = perevod_mant(mantissa);
    return 0;
}
void nuuuumber(unsigned long long x, int p)
{
    unsigned long long b = x;

    b >>= 23 - p;
    x <<= 41 + p;
    x >>= 41 + p;
    printf("%d.", b);
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x * 10;
        unsigned long long a = x;
        a >>= 23 - p;
        printf("%d", a);
        x <<= 41 + p;
        x >>= 41 + p;

    }
}

unsigned sdvigmant(unsigned x)
{
    x <<= 9;
    x >>= 9;
    x = x | 040000000;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    union
    {
        unsigned one;
        float number;
    }NUMBERS;
    char order10, order2;
    int sign;
    float two, NUMBER;
    unsigned u, mantisssa;
    printf("Enter the number: "); scanf_s("%f", &NUMBERS.number);
    NUMBERS.number > 0 ? sign = 0 : sign = 1;
    printf("Harakteristika:");
    if (NUMBERS.number < 0)
    {
        NUMBERS.number *= -1.0;
    }
    u = NUMBERS.one;
    two = NUMBERS.number;
    order10 = charact(NUMBERS.number);
    order2 = perevod_charact(charact(two));
    if (NUMBERS.number <= 1.0)
        NUMBERS.one = lessone(NUMBERS.number);
    else NUMBERS.one = morethanone(NUMBERS.number);
    printf(" %d ", sign);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", charactir[i]);
    }
    printf("  Mantissa:  ");
    for (int i = 1; i < 24; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", mant[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Veshestvennoe = ");
    if (sign == 1)
        printf("-");
    mantisssa = sdvigmant(u);
    nuuuumber(mantisssa, order10);
    printf("\n Porydok:%d", order10);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если реализация конвертера не самоцель, лучше сделать по-другому, посмотрите основной ответ здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number
Там конвертер можно и в обратную сторону использовать, но один момент - там не сказано про отбрасываемую старшую единицу мантиссы - про это в Википедии есть.